# How to open Cygwin at the location of an opened project in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, cygwin

I can configure Cygwin as my terminal in Intellij by selecting the `Cygwin.bat` as shell path in `Tools > Terminal` settings.

I want it to open at the project folder. For example, If the project is at `c:\projects\project1` and I open `project1` when I'm clicking on the Terminal I expect the prompt to be at:

```sh
myuser@ /cygdrive/c/projects/project1
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from [this forum post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000056510-cygwin-bash) should help:

```
"c:\cygwin64\bin\sh" -lic 'cd -; exec bash'
```

Comment: Also, after setting the above shell path remember to restart your Intellij. It did not work properly without restarting for me. For example, some commands in my `.bashrc` did not work